# SVG: get group coordinates (matrix or transform) in java

Tags: java, svg

I'm processing a SVG file using java.

It contains several groups that do not overlap: each group has a transform attribute with value *translate(x,y)* or *matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)* and contains one rect and one text. The SVG file looks like a chessboard: each group is a chessboard square.

Using org.w3c.dom.* classes I'm able to open the SVG file and read its properties. I need to understand in Java if a group A is on the left/right/top/bottom of a group B.

My question: how to get and compare the position of each group?

Thanks.

Comment: load it in Batik and call getBBox().

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Due to licenses, it's not possible to include Batik in the web application that uses the SVG file. I wonder if there is a way to get each group coordinates. If all groups used just translate, the "x,y" couple allows to understand how groups are positioned.